# Visual Studio 2017 debug + double click on a component will not jump/create to the code

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017

When I double click on a button in the designer while debug is running, 
it doesn't bring me to to Button1_Click event (nor create it if not assigned).

Double click works in design mode of course, 
but all previous VS: 2010, 2008, 2013 did have this behavior in debug mode.
(at least, in default setting)

Yes, it is not a good habit(?),but i really could use it.
Is it possible to enable this action in the debug mode in 2017?

Thanks in advance.

Picture:
In design-time, double click on the button will jump/create to the click() code.
But if i do the same thing @ running debug mode, nothing will happen.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could share us a screen shot about this issue, I test it in my VS2013, if I debug the app firstly, and then just click the button in the UI, it would not jump to the button click event unless I add a breakpoint in Button click event. If you mean that it doesn't create the code after you double click the button in winform designer, one possible reason is that your project files was not loaded correctly, for example, create a new Form app, view the result.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/POrNVJD.png

Comment: It is more a behavior issue, just not sure if MS changed the default setting(?). All my previous VS have this behavior. The test in the picture is made from empty web site, no code jumping/ creating in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

I think I could repro this issue in VS2010, but in VS2013 and VS2017, it really has no this feature. Maybe I use the latest vs2013 update version.

[image]

I help you report this issue to the product team here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/147191/visual-studio-2017-debug-double-click-on-a-compone.html

You could add your comment and vote this issue in above developer community site.

Comment: Oh i post one via 2017's "Report a Problem" and it was moved to "Triaged" category as well. The latest update doesn't change this behavior either, not sure if they intentionally to change this as default, or simply forget it

Comment: @Alex C., You could just add your comment in that reported submitted by me, and vote it. Not very sure that product team will add that feature back to latest version, but at least, we would get information from them. Of course, if possible, you could mark my reply as the  temporary answer, so other community members who meet the same issue could find the report easily, and then vote it. Have a nice day:)